# Embedded Jetty replacing suburl

Tags: embedded-jetty

Hi I am providing HTTP Server with Embedded Jetty

For some reason, some requests have to be received with suburl containing dots.
Example : http://127.0.0.1:10000/./test/

But when I retrieve suburl from jetty, the dot is replaced automatically.

Is there any way to stop replacing ?

Thanks
Jae

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a dark corner of the servlet spec that is not well defined (and has [had discussion on the servlet spec experts group mailing list](https://java.net/projects/servlet-spec/lists/jsr369-experts/archive/2016-09/message/31) as recently as a 2 months ago!)

The spec says the incoming URLs have to be "normalized" before being matched against a contextPath or urlPattern.

Normalization of a URI/URL is done for a number of reasons (spec requirements, security, prevent access outside of context, cleanup directory traversals, apply constraints correctly, etc..)

Things that are normalized (assuming 3 deployed contexts at `/foo` and `/bar`, and `/`):

- `/foo` -> `/foo/`
- `/foo/../bar/` -> `/bar/`
- `/foo/../../../etc/passwd` -> `/etc/passwd`
- `/foo/css//main.css` -> `/foo/css/main.css`
- `/foo/app/./css/./widget.css` -> `/foo/app/css/widget.css`

Then take this monster ...

- `/foo/context/.//..%2F..//./%62%61%72/context/servlet/info` -> ??

Jetty currently normalizes this down to `/bar/context/servlet/info`, but the strictest interpretation of the servlet spec (a very unpopular interpretation among the servlet spec implementers!) says it should:

- match on `/foo` context
- getContextPath() returns  `/foo/context/.//..%2F..//./%62%61%72/context/servlet/info`
- getPathInfo() returns `/context/.//..%2F..//./%62%61%72/context/servlet/info`

This ugly part of the spec is very hostile towards security efforts and is likely going to be refined/clarified in Servlet 4.0